# How to use -Xrunjvmhook and write my own agent

Tags: java, jvm, hp-uft

HP UFT program adds some options when starting Java to interfere with the java app to be able to test it.
If your write java -version you get this result after installing HP UFT:

> Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook
>   Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:"C:\Program Files >(x86)\HP\Unified Functional Testing\bin\java_shared\classes";"C:\Program Files (x
>   86)\HP\Unified Functional Testing\bin\java_shared\classes\jasmine.jar"

The file that is loaded is jasmine.jar and I would like to load my own jar file instead, but I can't find any documentation on how to use -Xrunjvmhook or how to write my own agent.

Comment: what do you man by loading your own jar file ? can you precisely word your question here

Comment: @jigar-joshi Obviously HP loads their own agent jasmine.jar to be able to interfere with Java application running. I would like to load my own agent and the agent is in the form of a jar-file.

Comment: @user1857773 _JAVA_OPTIONS is an environment variable. You can build your jar and add it to the environment variable.